# Fetch value from array saved in a single column in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arrayobject

I would like to get a single value from an array which is has been saved in a single mysql column in Laravel.

My mysql table columns look like this from the Controller:

```
$registrations = RegistrationLog::groupBy('phone_number')->get();
```

[image]

I would like to get into the request object section and get the email address value from the that array which is saved in the request_object column.

Please let me know how I can achieve this in laravel because I have tried using the below code inside a foreach in the blade but throws a 'Trying to get property of non-object error'

The code:

```
@foreach($registrations as $reg)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {!! $reg->request_object->email !!}
        </td>   
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is the information in the image live data? Or is this just some factory/faker data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mutation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), to format eloquent property like you want befor access. Also you can use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) which will be applied when you call ->toArray() method to Eloquent model. Or just `json_decode($reg->request_object)->email`

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like an "array" in your column, this looks like a JSON string.

Assuming this data is in a valid JSON format: In your RegistrationLog model, you need to use [JSON to Array casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) so the column is decoded into an array.

```
class RegistrationLog extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'request_object' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Then you can access it as `$reg->request_object['email']`

Comment: I also noticed my JSON was actually a JSON string and the cast can also worked on the same.